# Using JS to calculate elements in a PHP while loop

Tags: javascript, php

I have 2 `<p>` tags and an input field, wrapped in a while loop

```
<p id="price"></p>
<input  id="quantity"  oninput="calculate(<?php echo $cprice; ?>)" type="text" name="quantity">
<p id="total"></p>
```

I want to use JavaScript to perform arithmetic.

I want to multiply price and quantity and display the result in total. Without the while loop, it works but with the while loop, it only updates the first field.

```
function calculate(price) {
        var quantity = document.getElementById('quantity').value;
        var result = document.getElementById('total');  
        var myResult = price * quantity;
        document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = myResult;
}
```

I don't know how to dynamically update the `total` tag with js

Comment: You cannot have duplicate IDs - use a class

Comment: And show us your markup and code with `while` loop

Comment: @u_mulder that is pretty obvious

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your IDs to class since IDs must be unique.

See example which is assuming price is alway there

I choose to not use nextElement since you can easily add other stuff to the html without it

I also made the code unobtrusive instead of having inline handlers

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".quantity").forEach(function() {
  this.oninput = function() {
    var q = document.querySelectorAll(".quantity"),
      p = document.querySelectorAll(".price"),
      total = 0;
    q.forEach(function(qt, index) {
      var price = +p[index].innerText,
        quantity = +qt.value;
      if (!isNaN(quantity)) total += price * quantity;
    })
    document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = total;
  }
})
```

```html
<p class="price">1</p>
<input class="quantity" type="text" name="quantity">
<p class="price">2</p>
<input class="quantity" type="text" name="quantity">
<p class="price">3</p>
<input class="quantity" type="text" name="quantity"><br/>
Total:<p id="total"></p>
```

Comment: With your code, there's only 1 total. I'm sorry I didn't explain it better, but I want each price and quantity to have its own total

Answer (score 0):

IDs need to be unique. If there are duplicates, `document.getElementById` will return the first one.

Instead of using IDs, use DOM navigation methods. You can pass in `this` to get a reference to the input element, then find the output element after it.

```js
function calculate(price, input) {
  var quantity = input.value;
  var result = input.nextElementSibling;
  var myResult = price * quantity;
  result.innerHTML = myResult;
}
```

```html
<p class="price">Price = 30</p>
<input class="quantity" oninput="calculate(30, this)" type="text" name="quantity">
<p class="total"></p>

<p class="price">Price = 45</p>
<input class="quantity" oninput="calculate(45, this)" type="text" name="quantity">
<p class="total"></p>
```

Comment: This code works without styling, the moment i add it to a styled version of the code, it displays the result in a different place. Maybe its because I don't understand the `nextElementSibling`

Comment: It returns the next element that's the child of the same parent. If you add additional elements in between, or wrap them, you'll need to do more complex navigation to match that. jQuery makes this kind of thing easier, using its `.closest()` and `.find()` methods.

Comment: there's only 1 element in between, how should I navigate?

Comment: Real programmers read the documentation if they're not sure how something works. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling

Comment: `input.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling`